# VBS html extraction line

Tags: vbscript

Hi guys i need litlle help. I have some web page with this line in his html:

```
 <h3 class="entity-title"><a name="33333" class="link" href="/xy/xy-33333">some text</a></h3>
```

i want VBScript which open web page and find this line and copy "/xy/xy-33333" to some string variable. name,href and some text are always random

i have this part (saving all HTML to file.txt)

```
Dim oXMLHTTP
Dim oStream

Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")

oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", "http://www.yyy.com", False
oXMLHTTP.Send

If oXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write oXMLHTTP.responseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile "c:\te\file.txt"
    oStream.Close
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
...

If oXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
  Set html = CreateObject("HTMLfile")
  html.write oXMLHTTP.responseText
  For Each h3 In html.getElementsByTagName("h3")
    If h3.getAttribute("class") = "entity-title" Then
      For Each a In h3.getElementsByTagName("a")
        WScript.Echo a.href
      Next
    End If
  Next
End If
```

Comment: thanks on your answer but it is not complete solution. i only need class "entity-title" and this code get all h3 class. is it possible to get specific class?

Comment: @josiplegionares Simply filter for elements having a `class` attribute with that value. See updated answer.

Comment: thanks, i only needed to change "class" to "className". it works now