# extracting date from <div class>

Tags: vbscript

is there is some way to extract 24.11.2014. from:

```
<h3 class="entity-title"><a name="33333" class="link" href="/xy/xy-33333">some text</a></h3>

<div class="entity-thumbnail">
...
</div>

<div class="entity-description">
...
</div>

<div class="pub"><span class="label">now:</span> <time class="date date--full" datetime="2014-11-24T00:26:49+01:00" pubdate="pubdate">24.11.2014.</time>
                    </div>
```

i tried getElementByid("").innerHTML but it is not working because there is no id

Comment: do you have the option of giving it an id? If not, maybe getElementsByTagName() can help.

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27071632/vbs-html-extraction-line), only this time you need to search for `<div>` and `<time>` tags instead of `<h3>` and `<a>`.